# Dynamic change of field color in the HTML commune depending on the value

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

the columns 'surplus' and 'deficiency' give me differences in times, the problem is that I have to distinguish them somehow.

I am new in the subject, the point is that if the value of the field in these two columns were different from 00:00 it would change the color to a different one.

But only the individual field, not the entire column. Anyone got an idea?

[Edit fiddle - JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/blackZombie/gsxmh3do/2/)[^]

Code with table html

```js
function diff(start, end) {
  start = start.split(":");
  end = end.split(":");
  const startDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, start[0], start[1], 0);
  const endDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, end[0], end[1], 0);
  let diff = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
  const hours = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60);
  diff -= hours * 1000 * 60 * 60;
  const minutes = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60);
  return (hours <= 9 ? "0" : "") + hours + ":" + (minutes <= 9 ? "0" : "") + minutes;
}

function diffMs(start, end) { // this function can help you calculate a difference for a logical purposes
  return +start.split(":").join('') - +end.split(":").join('');
}
document.querySelector('table').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  const classList = e.target.classList
  if (classList.contains('start') || classList.contains('end')) {
    //retrieve the associated inputs
    const tr = e.target.parentNode.parentNode
    const [start, end, actual, normative, surplus, deficiency] = [...tr.querySelectorAll('.start,.end,.actual,.normative,.surplus,.deficiency')]
    const value = diff(start.value, end.value);
    actual.value = value
    if (diffMs(actual.value, normative.value) >= 0) {
      surplus.value = diff(normative.value, actual.value);
    }
    if (diffMs(actual.value, normative.value) <= 0) {
      deficiency.value = diff(actual.value, normative.value);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>start</th>
      <th>end</th>
      <th>actual</th>
      <th>normative</th>
      <th>surplus</th>
      <th>deficiency</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="day">
      <td><input type="time" class="start" id="start_1" value="08:00"></td>
      <td><input type="time" class="end" id="end_1" value="15:00"></td>
      <td><input type="time" class="actual" id="actual_1" value="07:00" readonly></td>
      <td><input type="time" class="normative" id="normative_1" value="08:00" readonly></td>
      <td><input type="time" class="surplus" id="surplus_1" value="00:00" readonly></td>
      <td><input type="time" class="deficiency" id="deficiency_1" value="00:00" readonly></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="day">
      <td><input type="time" class="start" id="start_2" value="08:00"></td>
      <td><input type="time" class="end" id="end_2" value="17:00"></td>
      <td><input type="time" class="actual" id="actual_2" value="09:00" readonly></td>
      <td><input type="time" class="normative" id="normative_2" value="08:00" readonly></td>
      <td><input type="time" class="surplus" id="surplus_2" value="00:00" readonly></td>
      <td><input type="time" class="deficiency" id="deficiency_2" value="00:00" readonly></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Notes:**
I don't want to using id because, I have records over 30

Values ​​from two columns refer to this case 'surplus' and 'deficiency'

Comment: Won't accessing the input element using the ID (for instance: "deficiency_2") and change the background color of it, do the trick?

Comment: I don't want to using id because, I have records over 30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9v8pjqna/

In the conditions where you check the "difMs" of "surplus" or "efficiency",
add a another simple condition to check if their value is different than 0.
If so, access the input backgroundColor property and change it.

```
if (diffMs(actual.value, normative.value) >= 0) {
  surplus.value = diff(normative.value, actual.value);
  if(surplus.value != 0) {
    surplus.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
}
if (diffMs(actual.value, normative.value) <= 0) {
  deficiency.value = diff(actual.value, normative.value);

  if(deficiency.value != 0) {
    deficiency.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not try this but, maybe you could do this with a selector:

```
input[type='time', value>='0'] <!-- any value -->
```

Comment: I can't because only the values ​​from two columns refer to this case